# Обьясните регулярное выражение

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

```
@"^[a-z]+(\s""[^/*?""<>|]+""|\s[^/*?"" <>|]+)*$"
@"^[a-z]+|(?<=\s"")[^/*?""<>|]+(?="")|(?<=\s)[^/*?"" <>|]+"
```

Обьясните, пожалуйста, подробно данные выражения более простым языком, желательно разделив данные выражения на более простые

Comment: Есть хороший сайт, который расписывает регулярки по шагам, правда на английском: для вашей первой регулярки http://regex101.com/r/dZ1qX4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как то так

```
@"^
[a-z]+ # символы в нижнем регистре, от 1 и более
(
  \s""[^/?""<>|]+"" # пробел, кавычка, затем от одного и более символов, но не /?"<>| и после этого есть кавычка
  |\s[^/?"" <>|]+  # тоже, но без кавычек.
)
* # то, что в скобках, может повторятся от нуля до бесконечности
$"

@"^
[a-z]+  # 1 и более символов в нижнем регистре

| #  или

(?<=\s"") # убедиться, что перед этой позицией есть пробельный сивол и кавычка
[^/?""<>|]+(?="") # а дальше от одного и более символов, но не /?"<>| и пробела и после этого есть кавычка

| #  или

(?<=\s) # убедиться, что перед этой позицией есть пробельный сивол
[^/*?"" <>|]+   # а дальше от одного и более символов, но не /?"<>|
"
```

В целом, выражения очень подобные.

Первое выражение будет матчить строку вида `abc test "qwer" "dsds"`.

Возможно, если бы был известен контекст, было бы понятнее, для чего они.

Answer (score 2):

```
^[a-z]+(\s""[^/*?""<>|]+""|\s[^/*?"" <>|]+)*$
```

Матчим группу `(\s""[^/*?""<>|]+""|\s[^/*?"" <>|]+)*`, которая встречается 0 или > (квантификатор *) раз в строке, и которую должно предварять 1 или > (квантификатор +) символов из набора `[a-z]+`
Разберем теперь `(\s""[^/*?""<>|]+""|\s[^/*?"" <>|]+)`
Она состоит из 2 альтернатив (символ |):

```
\s""[^/*?""<>|]+""
```

и

```
 \s[^/*?"" <>|]+
```

В первой альтернативе первый символ обязательно пробельный, затем должны следовать 2 двойные ковычки подряд, затем 1 или более символов, кроме `/*?""<>|`, и вся эта группа должна завершиться еще парочкой двойных ковычек (пример: в '**abc ""something text""**' будет матчиться строка ' **""something text""**')

Вторая альтернатива предполагает ведущим символом пробельный символ, затем 1 или более символов, кроме `/*?"" <>|` (пример: в '**abc text**' будет матчиться строка ' **text**')

Вторая регулярка посложнее, но не намного.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/zP0oS4